# Why the MouseClick event doesn't work in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, events, charts, mouse

I have this piece of code:

```
Dim pointMove As New Point
Dim ukazovatko As Boolean = False
Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseMove
    If ukazovatko Then
        pointMove = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Label1.Location = New Point(e.X + Label1.Size.Width / 2, Chart1.Bottom)
        Label1.Text = Math.Round(Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X), 2)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Label1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Label1.Paint
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, Label1.DisplayRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
Private Sub Chart1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseClick
    ukazovatko = Not ukazovatko
End Sub
Private Sub Chart1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Chart1.Paint
    Chart1.Invalidate()
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim p As New Pen(Color.Red, 2)
    g.DrawLine(p, pointMove.X, 0, pointMove.X, Chart1.Size.Height)
End Sub
```

It works just fine within my [test application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jABAS.png). When I just copy-pasted the code into [another application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6dhx.png), it falls apart. I have found out that it doesn't even recognize Chart.MouseClick event. I was thinking that the problem may lie in tabControl, but I have no idea how to deal with it. Of course I have done a research prior this question, but It seems I am the only one who has ever encountred such a problem (:D). Also I would like to mention that I am beginner in programming, so I may be anaware of some very obvious solutios to this.

Comment: Make sure in your second app that the Form holding your code is declared as `WithEvents`. Somehting like `Dim WithEvents YourForm As New YourForm`

Comment: Also make sure you’ve attached the handler method to the events in the form designer’s properties

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you for your input. Since all not-chart-related events work, I suppose that's not the problem.

Comment: @Hursey that is interesing. I have come across similar recomendation when doing my research. Unfortunatelly provided code was in C# and not VB. net and as I am not fully acquainted with C#, I skipped it. Now I know I need to get back to it. Thank you!

Comment: In the designer, double click your target property.  This will give you the method stub,  then just copy your converted c# code

Comment: I don't know why, or how, but I fixed it. All I didt was moving down the chart-code part to very bottom of the code.

Comment: @PepaZdepa You can mark your question as answered than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last out of a pure desperation I tried to reorganize the code and I moved the chart code down to very bottom and it, somehow, fixed it.